# Heteroscedasticity across one dimension in a panel setting

Tags: regression, panel-data, heteroscedasticity, assumptions

I understand that in a regression setting, heteroscedasticity is present if the vector of residuals of a model has non-constant finite variance.

Say you have a (balanced) panel across $i \in I$ and $t \in T$. Thus, one gets a vector of residuals $\epsilon_{i,t}$ with length $I*T$. The approach I am familiar with is to check wether the variance is constant across this vector.

However, what if the variance $\epsilon_t$ varies for each $i$. That is, the variance of the residuals varies across the cross sections? One could apply the same questions to the variance across $t$, respectively. Does this necessarily imply heteroscedasticity across **both** $i$ and $t$, i.e. the aforementioned vector? If not - wouldn't this be a form of heteroscedasticity, too, as it would strongly imply differing model performance across $i$ (or $t$, respectively)?

Comment: Yes, it would surely be a form of heteroskedasticity!

Comment: Alright, and do the standard tests test for that? I was of the opinion they were only testing on a two-dimensional scope.